# Extract Date from pdf c#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, console-application

extracting the date when it lies in the first line same as the string

I've multiple pdf of the same format, all the pdf documents starts with string "BEGIN". Based on the string "BEGIN" I've to extract date which is in the second line. I was able to perform that code. 
However my problem is that there are few documents where Date (MM/DD/YYY) and the string "BEGIN" lies in the first line. Here I can't extract the date because it's considering different string which is in the next line.

Below is my code;

```
string text = string.Empty;
text += PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(R, i);
int BEGIN_Location = 0;
string sSbeginValue = string.Empty;


 if (text.Contains("BEGIN"))
{
 BEGIN_Location = text.IndexOf("BEGIN", 0);
 sSbeginValue = text.Substring(BEGIN_Location + 6, 10);
}
```

[image: Also here]

Comment: "_Here I can't extract the date because they are in same line._" Why not? The date and the word "BEGIN" appearing in the same line should not really make it impossible for you to extract the text/date...

Comment: I would recommend using knowledge about data nature. If following statements are true you can use siple regex expression to extract desired info:
1. Date is having specific format [Month]/[Date]/[Year]
2. A date is stated only once in the document and there is no information that may have similar structure.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the package you're using 'PdfTextExtractor', but you could try using the api's method's options (for instance: LocationTextExtractionStrategy() ) For reference: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/PdfTextExtractor.html

Comment: If you have two possible locations for the date, you have to check both the text before the "BEGIN" and after it. Whichever of them is a date decides which case you're in.

Answer (score 1):

here is my way to get date (xx.xx.xxxx) from pdf using Spire.Pdf

```
private string ParsePDF(string filepathname)
    {
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        document.LoadFromFile(filepathname);

        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
       string tex =  content.Append(document.Pages[0].ExtractText()).ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(tex);
        string pattern;
        pattern = @"\d{2,}.\d{2,}.\d{2,}";// 01_01_2019
        var m = Regex.Match(tex, pattern);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Value))
        {
            return m.Value.Substring(0);
        }
        return "";           
    }
```

Comment: **A** The question is clearly tagged [tag:itext]; do you want to imply that Spire.Pdf is an iText spin-off? **B** The problem of the OP is not parsing the date but finding the (correct) date the location of which appears to be dynamic; your answer completely ignores that.